# Monitor folder with FileSystemWatcher fails after first time

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

Many times a day I receive xml-files from different users. These are FTPed to a folder on my drive, say D:\batch. As today I check these files with a Scheduled Task which starts an ASP.NET page and processes the files found and answers the uploader and ends. This task is run every 15 minutes, but the uploaders wants the answers quicker, so I'm trying to accomplish this. I've created a Windows Service which monitors a folder, and when a file is created, it processes it.

I've followed a couple of different guides, but espically this one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32591/Creating-a-Windows-Service-for-Watching-System-Dir

With the first file it works, but everytime the second file is added, it crashes:

```
Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
Stack:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(System.String, System.String, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.IO.File.Copy(System.String, System.String)
   at FileMonitor.FilKigger.Watcher_Created(System.Object, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.OnCreated(System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32, UInt32,     System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

How come is this?

Some code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        Watcher.Path = "D:\\FTP\\Batch\\";
        Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_Created);
        Watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(Watcher_Deleted);
        Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
```

And here just the code which copies the file to a new folder.

```
void Watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        File.Copy(e.FullPath, "D:\\newFolder\\" + e.Name);
        Lg.WriteEntry("File moved", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }
```

Catching the exception just leaves the file, but ofcourse keeps the service running.

Comment: Cold you provide exception message, not only it's type? And if it has, please post Inner Exception too..

Comment: Where is this exception being thrown (which line of code)?

Comment: Keep in mind that the created event gets fired when the file is created. So, if it is a large file that is still being transferred, then the file is created (but not completed) and you want to start copying it already, but the file isn't really there yet. Sounds a bit vague.. Hope you get it. Maybe that's your problem as well.

Comment: at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   at FileMonitor.FilKigger.Watcher_Created(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e

Comment: Its just an empty file for checking, so there is some sort of problem... It's in the File.Copy the second time it's called.

Comment: There's not enough info in the stack trace you posted.  What's the exception's HResult value?  Other than that, this is entirely common.  You can't copy a file right after it got created, the app that created it still has the file opened.  You have to wait.

Comment: The weird thing is, that every first time I start the service and add a file, it's copied correctly. But now I've changed it, so the user have to add an "<name>.finished" file when done (could have done so the user should rename the file also). This seems to work. There's no workaround to see when a files is finished beeing FTPed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the watcher to find "_finish.txt"-files, which the user sends after the real file is uploaded

```
Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(ftpFolder, "*_finish.txt");
```

Then replacing the _finish with "", and I've got the real file which is guaranteed to be finished uploading...